# what method can I use to separate strings inside array into individual arrays (using JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
var array = ["Charizard,Pikachu,Glalie,Delfox"];
```

I tried to use the `split()` method except that only affects string variables and not arrays.

My ultimate goal is to make array = `["Charizard","Pikachu","Glalie","Delfox"];`

[image: Here's a picture that describes the problem]

Comment: So… `array[0].split(',')` then…!?

Comment: You can always do `[].concat(...array.map(e => e.split(',')))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of the array an split it using as delimiter the comma ','

```js
var array = ["Charizard,Pikachu,Glalie,Delfox"];
console.log(array[0].split(','))
```

Comment: thank you so much! It works!